# Kerberos over http documentation

Tags: authentication, kerberos, standards

The NTLM over HTTP documentation can be found here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ntht/f09cf6e1-529e-403b-a8a5-7368ee096a6a

Where is the Kerberos over HTTP official documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos over HTTP isn't officially developed by the [MIT project](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/).  It is implemented though using [GSSAPI](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/appdev/gssapi.html), and the extensions are described in [RFC 4559](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559).